# Boyfriend tourist/student visa denied 3 times

Tags: usa, visa-refusals, peruvian-citizens

My case has many issues. I am in a long-distance relationship with a man from South America. For 3 years he has been trying to enter the USA on his own and got denied 3 times a visa.

The first refusal was when he applied for his tourist visa. He waited a year and then applied to study English here in the US, they denied him again. He has done everything to prove he can return back to his country. The most recent refusal was section 214b. He wanted to do it on his own, so he applied for a student visa so he could study here in the USA and we can grow our relationship.

That’s impossible now because he’s been rejected 3 times. The first time, he applied to come for a vacation here in the USA. He put me as a family because in reality he's a distant cousin. They denied him the visa because he has family here. The next time, he applied for a student visa. The school itself in New York told him to tell immigration that he had no family here, but it was already on the record that he did say because of me.

The school offered him a chance to get a visa in the UK, so he left for a couple of months to the UK. When he came back to his home country, he decided to apply a year later again for a student visa. He was denied again even after proving ties. He has a family business and his uncle was going to pay for the whole trip.

He has no hope now and he believes that if we get married that visa will just be rejected too. He doesn’t want to do it based on marriage for fear of his past history. He wanted to try alone. Is there any way someone can offer me some advice?

[image]